# Variant return type Upcasting Overriding c++

Tags: c++, polymorphism, overriding, upcasting

I have problem with `clone()` method in the following example. I have expected that `sizeof(*((*ptr1).clone()))` would be the same as `b1` and `sizeof(*(ptr2.clone()))` would be the size of `c1` but they are not. They are `sizeof(a1)`. What am I missing?

Here is the code.

```
class A
{int a;
public:
    virtual A * clone() {return this;}
};

class B : public A
{int b,c;
public:
    B * clone() {return this;}
};

class C : public A
{int b,c,d;
public:
    C * clone() {return this;}
};

int main()
{
    A a1;
    B b1;
    C c1;
    A * ptr1 = &b1;
    A & ptr2 = c1;
    std::cout << "sizeof(a1) = " << sizeof(a1) << '\n';
    std::cout << "sizeof(b1) = " << sizeof(b1) << '\n';
    std::cout << "sizeof(*(b1.clone())) = " << sizeof(*(b1.clone())) << '\n';
    std::cout << "sizeof(c1) = " << sizeof(c1) << '\n';
    std::cout << "sizeof(*((*ptr1).clone()))" << sizeof(*((*ptr1).clone())) << '\n';
    std::cout << "sizeof(*(ptr2.clone()))" << sizeof(*(ptr2.clone())) << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sizeof` only takes the static type of its argument into account, not the dynamic type.  Thus the argument to `sizeof` can be an unevaluated operand, and the result of `sizeof` does not depend on any run-time information (such as vtables required for dynamic type information).  And so the result of `sizeof` is always a compile-time constant expression, suitable to be used e.g. as a template argument.

See C++11: §5.3.3 [expr.sizeof]/2.

Answer (score 2):

`sizeof(*((*ptr1).clone()))` is a compile time value, and expression is not executed.

so here we have `sizeof(*((*std::declval<A*>()).clone()))` which is `sizeof(A)` (we use `A::clone()` which returns `A*`).